# Dúvida entre usar chave primária composta ou não na tabela associativa

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework-6

Estou fazendo um relacionamento onde o mesmo seja N:N...

Exemplo:

> Projeto x Funcionario

Neste relacionamento eu crio uma tabela associativa chamada `Projeto_Funcionario` levando o id das duas classes.

> Projeto(id, nome)
>
> Funcionario(id, nome, cargo)
>
> Projeto_Funcionario(**idProjeto**, **idFunc**, cargaHoraria)

A dúvida é: gostaria de saber se as chaves idProjeto e idFunc são chaves primárias compostas ou não, ou apenos crio elas sendo estrangeiras e antes dela crio uma primária.

> Projeto_Funcionario(**id**, **idProjeto**, **idFunc**, cargaHoraria)

**OBS:** O Funcionário não pode trabalhar no mesmo projeto mais de uma vez, apenas **uma única vez**.

Comment: Não são compostas. Elas servem como o relacionamento 1 para N entre a tabela que faz o composto (Projeto_Funcionario) com a tabela normal (Projeto ou Funcionário).

Comment: Sim, eu sei que elas servem para o relacionamento 1 para N. Porém gostaria de saber **se as mesmas são chaves primárias compostas ou não.**

Comment: Como eu já falei, não são compostas. Se você quer que haja apenas um relacionamento, utilique UNIQUE como citaram

Comment: @RenanNarciso, como você criando seu modelo ? poderia posta? as classes.. Já adiantando com o Entity Framework, você só irar ter a tabela de relacionamento no banco de dados, com as duas colunas sendo chaves primarias compostas... e mais os campos que você precise.

Comment: tem um exemplo bem claro .. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Olá @MarconcilioSouza eu já consegui resolver o meu problema, de qualquer forma, obrigado!
Na minha classe associativa eu criei uma chave primária composta.
Abraços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso fica a seu critério.

Os dois jeitos estão certos, mas eu acho bem chato trabalhar com chaves primárias compostas, pois para fazer referência à elas por chave estrangeira, você precisa das duas colunas. Imagina o caos para adicionar uma nova coluna primária nessa tabela? Você vai precisar acrescentá-la em todas as outras tabelas que dependem da chave antiga.

Também dá mais trabalho ficar passando duas variáveis no código do cliente, então prefiro fazer dessa forma:

```
CREATE TABLE Projeto_Funcionario (
    id INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
    idProjeto INT NOT NULL,
    idFunc INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Projeto_Funcionario PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_Projeto_Funcionario UNIQUE (idProjeto, idFunc),

    /* chaves estrangeiras... */
)
```

Com uma CONSTRAINT do tipo UNIQUE, você tem a mesma garantia de unicidade que você teria com uma chave primária, e o SQL Server ainda te cria um índice para essas colunas.

Agora, ao tentar fazer um INSERT nessa tabela, vinculando o mesmo funcionário com o mesmo projeto, o SGBD vai apontar erro de violação da CONSTRAINT.

```
-- esse primeiro insert funciona
INSERT INTO Projeto_Funcionario (idProjeto, idFunc)
VALUES (1, 1)

-- esse não
INSERT INTO Projeto_Funcionario (idProjeto, idFunc)
VALUES (1, 1)

-- erro: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UNIQUE_Projeto_Funcionario'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Projeto_Funcionario'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1).
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/be715/3)**.

Comment: Mas as FKs continuam?

Comment: Sim, as chaves estrangeiras você mantém.

Comment: Não to entendendo mto bem, mas e em relação a restrição que tem no meu sistema?
No caso, o Funcionário não pode ter trabalhado em projetos repetidos, APENAS UMA VEZ NO PROJETO.
Para isso, qual é o ideal para se usar? Chave primária composta?

Comment: Renan, complementei minha resposta, dê uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

Não geram chave composta, uma forma de travar a inserção de itens duplicados é criando `index`.

O código seria mais ou menos assim:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Entity<Projeto_Funcionario>().Property(a => a.idProjeto).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                           new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_PROJETO_FUNCIONARIO_UNIQUE", 1) { IsUnique = true }));

      modelBuilder.Entity<Projeto_Funcionario>().Property(a => a.idFunc).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                           new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_PROJETO_FUNCIONARIO_UNIQUE", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
}
```

Com essa configuração ele irá bloquear a inserção de `id` de projeto e de funcionário duplicados e irá lançar uma exceção. Todavia, acredito que mesmo com a adição do `index` seria melhor fazer uma validação antes de tentar inserir as informações.

**EDIT**

Segue como eu deixaria a classe:

```
public class Projeto_Funcionario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CargaHoraria { get; set; }

    public int IdProjeto { get; set; }
    public Projeto Projeto { get; set; }

    public int IdFunc { get; set; }
    public Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Isso, a minha idéia é **deixar o funcionário trabalhar em vários projetos**, porém, **ele não pode trabalhar em projetos repetidos**. A solução simples e ideal para isso, não seria criar apenas chave primária composta na tabela associativa?
Um exemplo que fiz no meu context: https://ghostbin.com/paste/cdnyp

Comment: isso também é uma solução, porém eu faria a junção da minha resposta com a do amigo de cima, ou seja, pegaria a classe Projeto_Funcionario criaria um `FK` para ela e a criaria `index` para `idProjeto` e `IdFunc`.

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando como eu faria a classe.

Comment: Sim, a minha classe associativa fiz desse mesmo jeito, porém na hora de criar o _migration_ ela não está como **chave primária composta**. Com essa restrição de dominio do meu sistema, é ideal criar chave composta? (É essa a dúvida)

Comment: Entendi, acho que é baseado em opinião sua pergunta, a minha opinião é que não vale a pena criar chave composta. Vale a pena criar a classe com uma `FK` normal, adicionar os relacionados, e criar o `index` para travar a adição de dados duplicados.